# "Weich gekochtes Ei" and "hart gekochtes Ei": What may be called a boiled egg harder than the former and softer than the latter?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

For the English "a hard-/soft-boiled egg" I've found the German equivalents "ein hart/weich gekochtes Ei" (for a runny egg,  also "ein wachsweich gekochtes Ei"), but I couldn't find the German word for what in Russian is called "в мешочек".  Its English equivalent "medium-boiled egg" doesn't fit exactly, as by the hardness-softness of the yoke criterion it is a bit harder than a runny egg and a tad softer than a medium boiled one. It cooks in simmering water exactly three minutes. Is there a German word that could meet this criterion of a boiled egg?

Comment: It's a *Drei-Minuten-Ei*.

Comment: @Janka - This easy? And if it boiled four or five minutes, it would become a _Vier-/Fünf-Ninuten Ei_, wouldn't it??

Comment: @Rompey yep. That easy. But after just three minutes, I’d still expect a soft egg.

Comment: Yes, it is that simple. *Hartgekochtes Ei* is common too, *weichgekochtes Ei* not so much. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWjIX3h1C0Q

Comment: @Stephie - Well, maybe three and a half minutes, depending on the size and provided that the eggs don't come into the water and onto the cooker straight out of the fridge:-)

Comment: Soll das wachweiche Ei vielleicht ein wachsweiches sein?

Comment: @userunknown - Danke sehr.

Comment: @Rompey you seem to have misunderstood “wachsweich” im your question: not liquid (as you wrote), but means “firm white and a creamy yolk”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://www.tippscout.de/eier-kochen-so-gelingt-ein-perfektes-ei_tipp_2591.html) offers the term

> wachsweiches Ei

for the intermediate type, probably due to the consistency of solidifying liquid wax as well as an advanced cooking time calculator considering size and temperature of the egg.

Comment: For a medium-boiled egg PONS dictionary suggests ["Fünfminuten-Ei"](https://en.pons.com/translate?q=medium-boiled+egg&l=deen&in=en&lf=en). Is it also in use? I only started learning German to know for sure which bilingual online sources are reliable and which are not.

Comment: Wachsweich: firm whites, creamy yolks. Fits the description of the OP. (Except for the timing.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the pretty common

> "wachsweich"

, there's also the rather rare

> "pflaumenweich".

Both of these have a distinctly old-fashioned ring to them (esp. the latter).
Also, a quick google search came up with mentions of "pflaumenweich" but the few definitions give the impression that these two are somewhat interchangeable. Some people feel that plums are softer than wax, some think wax is softer than plums.

So, long story short: go with the easy and very unambiguous timescale-related descriptor. Three minutes is three minutes for (almost) everybody. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Frühstücksei" is what I've heard it referred to, even though that's a general term for any egg you eat at breakfast.

Most people in Germany expect an egg to be "Weichgekochtes" (between 3-5 minutes).

It was explained to me by several Germans that this is because "it takes more skill to cook than just boiling it for 10 minutes like anyone can do (i.e. in America)".

Terminology will, however, vary by region and/or town. Some might say as already said "Drei-Minuten-Ei" though I've never heard that in my 5 years here.

This article has a nice infographic as well as more explanations (in German of course).

http://www.brigitte.de/rezepte/kochtipps/eier-kochen--so-gelingt-das-fruehstuecksei-10832050.html